# How to call a method when 'No Cellular Network Available'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cellular-network

I am implementing an API based application. As per the requirements I need to show an alert when "No Cellular Network Available".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test reachability, use this sample code called [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

To show an alert, use [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertview).

Both are in Apple's documentation.
<sub>You don't have to say "you went through the documentation" or "it's urgent...". You can just ask questions! That's what Stack Overflow is for.</sub>